# Counting Values of Rows returned in a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table in my report that brings back 14 rows (Agent Names)
I now want to count the total of names to work out a deal per head ration but I keep getting 14 1's in a table. Can some please point me in the right direction as I cant get the expressions to bring back what I want.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are using the count expression in the details group. Edit your question to include the table you have and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [CountRows?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330(v=sql.100).aspx)

```
=CountRows("MyDataset")
```

Or use grouping in your tablix.